# C# コンソールアプリケーションでのウィンドウ位置の変更について

Tags: c#

Windowsでコンソールアプリケーションを作っています。
実行時にウィンドウ位置を変更したいのですがどうすればいいでしょうか？
APIで行う方法しかないのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問の実行時のウィンドウ位置というのは、コンソールアプリケーションを実行するプログラムのウィンドウ位置ということではないのでしょうか？それであれば、どういうプログラムを使ってどう実行してどう変更したいかを詳しく説明しなければ回答は不可能です。

Comment: コマンドプロンプトを開き、例えば
C:\> program.exe
としたときのウィンドウです。
幅や高さは
Console.WindowWidth
Console.WindowHeight
で変えています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yasuhiro Nijiさんが提示されたリンク先ではウィンドウ位置の変更方法として[`MoveWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534(v=vs.85).aspx)が提示されていますがこれは名前に反して移動だけでなくサイズ変更も強要されます。より柔軟な[`SetWindowPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx)を提案します。こちらは、ウィンドウの上下関係、位置、サイズ、再描画を行うか、をフラグで個別指定できます。
その際、操作にはウィンドウハンドルが必要です。しかしリンク先で提示されている`Process.MainWindowHandle`はコンソールアプリケーションでは正しく機能しません。コンソールアプリケーションでは[`GetConsoleWindow`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolewindow)で取得できます。

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags);
const int SWP_NOSIZE = 1;
const int SWP_NOZORDER = 4;

static void Main() {
    SetWindowPos(GetConsoleWindow(), IntPtr.Zero, 100, 100, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

WindowsのC#のコンソールアプリケーションでは、.NET Framework の[Console クラス](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx)にある機能は使えるので、`Console.WindowWidth`、`Console.WindowHeight`で幅と高さは簡単に変更できます。

しかしながら、Console クラスには、コマンドプロンプトのウィンドウ上の位置を変更するようなメソッド又はプロパティはないので、Win32 API を使わないとウィンドウ上の位置を変更することはできません。

もし、Win32 API を使ってでも実現したいのであれば、DOBON.NETの[この記事](https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/process/movewindow.html)が参考になると思います。